# pixel perfect collision andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I developing game using andengine and i used PixelPerfectSprite for pixel collistion.. But some time its detect wrong  collistion even its not collided.  [enter link description here](https://github.com/m5/andengine-pixel-perfect)

In this link..ie

**Pixel Perfect Collision Detection
Note: this will only work for collisions between unrotated, unscaled sprites.**

In my game i used sprite.setRotation.. Any other way to handle pixel collision using andengine

Comment: ppc doesn't work with rotation, you use rotation, you probably can figure out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

AndEngine Collision Extension: https://github.com/MakersF/AndEngineCollisionsExtension
This is an extension that aims to bring different collision methods (perfect or approximations) to AndEngine GLES2

Supported Collision Methods:
Pixel-Perfect Collision (supports: translation, scale, rotation, screw)
It also support pixel-perfect collision between pixel-perfect shapes and retangular shapes, without the need for the latter to be a pixel-perfect shape.
Alpha values different from 0 (you set the threshold that identify if a pixel is solid or not)
You ca unse the utils methods to check the performances in your app or to output the collision mask to check if it is what you need